Maximize expected stopping time of a random walk with absorbing barriers
Consider a discrete-time random process $\{X_t\}$ $(t = 0, 1, 2, \cdots)$ on the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^M$. Starting from the point $X_0 = (X^1_0, \cdots, X^M_0)$ satisfying
$$
X^1_0 + \cdots + X^M_0 = N \quad \text{and} \quad X^i_0 \geq 0,
$$
at each step, one nonzero component of $X_t$ is chosen uniformly at random and decreased by 1.
Define a stopping time $\tau$ as the first time when the process reaches a state where exactly one of the components $X^1, \cdots, X^M$ is nonzero (i.e., $X_t$ lies on one of the coordinate axes). Suppose $\Delta_N^M=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}^M\mid x_1+\cdots+x_M=N,x_k\ge0\}$. The goal is to maximize $\mathrm{E}[\tau\mid X_0]$ by choosing an optimal initial point $X_0 \in \Delta_N^M$.
Let $d$ denote the Manhattan distance. Then define a function
$$
f(y)=f(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_M):=\mathrm{E}[d(X_\tau,X_0)\mid X_0=y]=\mathrm{E}[\tau\mid X_0=y],
$$
which represents the expectation of the stopping time given the starting point $y\in\mathbb{Z}^M$. If there is exactly one of the components of $y$ equal to $0$, then $f(y)=0$. Our goal is to solve the following optimization problem
$$
\begin{align*}
\max_{y\in \Delta_N^M} f(y)
\end{align*}
$$
Due to the Markov property of $\{X_t\}$, we can derive the following recursive equation for $f(y)$
$$
\begin{align*} f(y_1,\cdots,y_M)&=\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^M\mathrm{1}_{y_k\ge 1}}\sum_{k=1}^M \left(1+f(y_1,\cdots,y_k-1,\cdots,y_M)\right)\mathrm{1}_{y_k\ge 1}\\ &=1+\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^M\mathrm{1}_{y_k\ge 1}}\sum_{k=1}^M f\left(y_1,\cdots,y_k-1,\cdots,y_M\right)\mathrm{1}_{y_k\ge 1}. \end{align*}
$$
For $M = 3$, I have calculated some specific cases. Below are some plots that show $f$ restricted to $\Delta_N^3$ for various values of $N$:

$f|_{\Delta_6^3}$:


$f|_{\Delta_{27}^3}$:


$f|_{\Delta_{100}^3}$:




In the above cases, it appears that the optimal solution occurs when $\max\limits_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq M} |y_i - y_j| \leq 1$.
I have only found this paper which seems to solve the problem for $M = 2$ and $M = 3$. However, I have not come across any other proofs or discussions addressing this problem for the general case.
